# Line break in :after pseudo-element content lost when pasted into editor

Tags: css, line-breaks

Below is the well-known method to add a line break using :after pseudo-element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .br:after {
            content: '\a';
            white-space: pre;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <span class="br">Line 1</span>
    <span class="br">Line 2</span>
    <span class="br">Line 3</span>
    <span class="br">Line 4</span>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when this html content copied and pasted from browser to an external editor, e.g. Notepad or Word, the line breaks are lost and the text above looks as

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: No, because pseudo elements don't exist in the DOM tree. An alternative/workaround would be to use another method for adding these line breaks.

Comment: To further illustrate @JoshC's point, see this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pCC6z/  Try selecting the text and notice that the pseudo-element text is not even selected.

Comment: 2 James: all text "Line 1abc Line 2abc Line 3abc Line 4abc " was copied-pasted. Don't see any issue. Indeed, I can't copy "abc" only but no problem to copy with root content.

Comment: 2JoshC: See James example below. It appeared to be no issue with textual content. The only issue with line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each `span` element to appear on a line of its own, you can set just

```
.br { display: block; }
```

If you want to have a line break only after a `span`, while letting it go to the same line as preceding content, then I’m afraid there’s no solution. As a clumsy workaround, you could include a visible character in the generated content and then do a search and replace in the target program to replace it by a line break.